# Store: Can't find product error

Tags: expresso-store, error, product

I'm adding Store to a site with a channel of existing products. Store installed correctly and works. I was getting this error when trying to add a product to my cart:

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors
Store: Can't find product (entry ID: 8238, modifiers [])
```

I figured out that if I add price to a product and save it in the Control Panel, it will allow me to add to cart. Since there are over 1000 products, I ran a sql to insert a row for each product entry_id into exp_store_products with a price of 0 and the other columns default, as this is the data that appeared to change when I added a price and saved the first product.

I also added [store] to the custom Store field for the products channel, as that is what I saw in the products I had saved already.

I still get the same error with all products, though in the Control Panel edit page for the entries the price shows up. Unless I save each product, its not working. I looked for some array stored somewhere, a cache file, etc. of all the entries that Store considers products, but don't see one.

What else can I do in bulk to get all these products to add to the cart? I don't want to click save on 1000 products in the Control Panel.

Comment: @adrian-macneil are you able to help on this one?

Comment: Do you products have modifiers set? I had a similar error occur when trying to add products to a cart without specifying a modifier. Your best bet anyway is probably to write a SQL query to INSERT rows into exp_store_products and the other store tables in bulk for all the entries you have in exp_channel_titles.

Comment: Just wanted to note this issue can also arise on checkout if you use `{exp:store:product}` tags inside of `{exp:store:checkout}` tags. Presumably because of nested forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to update exp_store_stock with some basic info.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I swear I checked every table for data. Not sure how I missed that. Added the rows for each product there and we're good!