# Add to cart: "Store: Can't find product (entry ID: 3242, modifiers [])"

Tags: expresso-store, safecracker

I found a [question posted based on the same error](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30637/store-cant-find-product-error), but my issue happens in a different scenario.

Example: I have "Product A" with status "Status 1".

Adding it to cart works as expected.

When I use channel:form to change its status to "Status 2", and then try adding it to cart, I get this error:

```
Store: Can't find product (entry ID: 3242, modifiers [])
```

If I change from "Status 1" to "Status 2" in the control panel, adding the product to cart works as expected. It seems that channel form is causing a problem here.

My channel form code:

```
{exp:channel:form
 channel="inquiries"
 entry_id="{entry_id}"
 return="wallpapers/sms"
}

 <input name="title" type="text" value="{title}" readonly hidden>

 <select name="status" id="status">
  <option value="Status 2" selected="selected">Status 2</option>
 </select>
```

{/exp:channel:form}

Does anyone have a clue about this one? Cheers!

**Edit:** To be clear, editing the status with channel:form works (at least the status change is reflected in the control panel, it's just that Store throws a fit)

Comment: Turns out the solution posted here worked in my case as well: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30637/store-cant-find-product-error